# The parser is unchanged. There are no new keywords or statements

Tags: mysql, database-performance, process-monitoring

I am studying the explanation on this page:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema.html

and I do not understand the following:

> 1. Server monitoring occurs continuously and unobtrusively with very little overhead. Activating the Performance Schema does not make the server unusable.
> 2. The parser is unchanged. There are no new keywords or statements.

can anyone help me give a simple explanation?

Comment: It simply means that uses of the _performance schema_ have not changed from 5.7.  _Other_ things in 8.0 have had major changes (relative to 5.7).

Answer (score 1):

There is no change to your normal query SQL. This just enables performance data collection on the MySQL server.

See an example of the usage below:

https://www.ip2location.com/tutorials/lookup-ip-proxy-optimization-mysql